# What is the best way to write a long sentence or paragraph using Roman typeface?

Tags: support, mathjax

First of all I am not very sure if my question belongs to this site. It can get downvoted or asked for deletion. My apologies beforehand if this is the case.

I often encountered the necessity to write a lemma, a theorem or a problem (which is composed by merely words) in maths but I couldn't find a way of how to do it with Roman typeface. As it is customary use in formulas.

I'm aware that to write a long set of words can be done by just typing it in the box Stack provides as I'm doing it now by writing this question. But this method does not help too much to address a clear difference between which part of the problem is the "mathematical problem itself" and the "problem within the problem".

Although I could use cursive, bold and even quote or pre formatted text as given in the options none of this feels right as it does not match with what is used in mathematical context. Therefore, is there any alternative for avoiding to use recursively:

```
\textrm{}
```

or more properly,

```
\mathrm{}
```

As each time I want to write a long sentence I end up splitting the latter and calling the instruction over and over again.

```
\mathrm{This is an example text. This is an example text}

\mathrm{This is an example text. This is an example text}
```

Therefore, How to write a paragraph using Roman typeface, is there a tutorial for this?.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want specifically. Another font than the default one?

Comment: Why do you want to use mathjax for this?

Comment: @quid I am looking to use Roman instead of the default font serif for one part in the text and then close that paragraph and return to the default font.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am a bit astonished by your assertion that it is not customary to typeset lemmas and theorems in italic as it is very common.

Comment: @quid I think you misinterpreted what I wanted to mean. I could use italic but instead Can it be done using a different typeface instead?. Not because is a merely caprice or anything. But it would be more in tone with what is shown in the formulas as both use the same typeface. Therefore distinguishing it from other parts in the text which composes the question itself.

Comment: Alright. Either way, changing the font is not really supported for a reason. With all due respect to your personal preference, it'd be desirable you just  would not do this. And, especially do not use MathJax for substantial amounts of  text (or in fact most any text outside of formulas.)

Comment: @quid Yet the reason to me is not very clear other than just accepting it the way it is a-la dogmatic. Since this site is driven by norms I'll have just accept them, although I disagree with certain recommendations.

Answer (score 10):

You don't. Generally speaking, sites with user-generated content make a deliberate design decision not to offer such a feature.

The general philosophy is that it's the user's job to provide *content* (e.g. marking things as requiring emphasis or strong emphasis), and it's the website's (and/or browser's) job to provide the *styling* (e.g. choosing an italic or bold font).

You're asking to specify the styling yourself. And (it seems) SE deliberately does not want to allow that.

There are various reasons for strictly adhering to such a separation; going into them is beyond the scope of the post.

Comment: Your last sentence has just opened my curiosity, where discussions regarding user customization and styles should be held?. I must point out that as a relatively new user I'm adjusting with the style and the options and tools offered by SE and is my desire to harvest the best they can offer.